# ROS2 Pybind11 help needed

Tags: ros, ros2, catkin, python, colcon

https://github.com/chrissunny94/floam

I am on a pressing issue to bring in Python support for FLOAM .

I am currently facing a lot of issues getting

1. linking libraries
2. namespaces
3. object oriented approach

Kindly share some pointers on this .

Kindly share some elaborate projects where Pybind11 has been employed to wrap C++ .

Adding keywords for future folks to find this .
ROS2 , FLOAM , SLAM ,PCL ,AMENT ,CMAKE , ROS , CATKIN , COLCON

Comment: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/discussions/4851


I have posted a diicussion on Pybind11 github page also

Comment: https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/blob/rolling/rosbag2_py/CMakeLists.txt

Here is a usefull example

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.